# Conditional statement using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to treat a large amount of files, according to the following rule :

If the file starts with `#`, then insert a `#` at the beginning of the second line.
Else, insert `#` at the beginning of the file.

To insert `#` at the beginning of the 1st line, I would do `sed '1s/^/#/' myfile`

To insert `#` at the beginning of the 2nd line, I would do `sed '2s/^/#/' myfile`

However, I miss the conditional logic here. How can I do to sequence those actions according to the conditional statement I wrote above using only sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` has the right logic, but not sure how to use with multiple files

```
awk 'FNR==1 {if (/^#/) {print;getline};print "#"$0;next} 1' file
```

Comment: You can use `FNR` instead of `NR` for multiple files since `FNR` will get reset to 1 upon reading a new file.

Answer (score 2):

If only for didactic purposes, here's a sed line that actually uses conditional branching:

```
sed '1{s/^\([^#]\)/#\1/;t;n;s/^/#/}'
```

Roughly:

```
if on the first line:
    if the line starts with anything other than '#'
        insert '#' at the beginning
    else
        print the line as is
        read the next line
        insert '#' at the beginning
```

Shorter, but with unconditional branching instead:

```
sed '1{/^#/{n;s/^/#/;b};s/^/#/}'
```

Roughly:

```
if on the first line:
    if the line starts with '#'
        print the line
        read the next line
        insert '#' at the beginning
        skip to the end
    (implied else)
        insert '#' at the beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is not well suited to this sort of thing, but this should work:

```
sed  '1{ /^#/{N;s/\n/\
#/; }; /^#/!s/^/#/; }; '
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1{N;/^#/s/\n/&#/;t;s/^/#/}' file
```

Read the first two lines and if the first line starts with a `#` insert a `#` on the second line or insert a '#` in the first line if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty readable way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""}
     NR==1 {if(/^#/){PRE="#"} else {sub(/^/,"#",$0)} print;next}
     {print PRE,$0;PRE=""}' file
```

The BEGIN{} sets the field separator.

The second line applies to line 1 of your file and either sets a PREFIX to `#` for the next line, or substitutes a `#` in at the start of the current line. Then it is printed and the next statement avoided.

The third line prints all subsequent lines of the file, the second with a prefix of `#` if required.